# Scrollbar inside scrolling modal not clickable

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning-design-system, scrolling

I'm using the [latest Appiphony Strike components](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components) to built a [multiselect picklist](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/tree/master/aura/strike_multiSelectPicklist) inside a [modal](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/tree/master/aura/strike_modal).

```
<aura:component >
   <c:strike_modal title="Strike Modal" showModal="true">
           <c:strike_multiSelectPicklist >
               <c:strike_option label="Option" />
               <c:strike_option label="Option" />
               <c:strike_option label="Option" />
               <c:strike_option label="Option" />
               <c:strike_option label="Option" />
               <c:strike_option label="Option" />
           </c:strike_multiSelectPicklist>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
       <br/>
    </c:strike_modal>
</aura:component>
```

As shown in the screencast I am unable to click the scrollbar in the select options. It always closes the select box.

[image]

This symptom doesn't show up when I don't have the modal around.

The Strike code is just using the Lightning design system, so my assumption is that this is a general problem, why I am putting my question here [and here](https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/issues/200).

Comment: Any errors when you click on it?

Comment: Yeah, I don't think we can help you with this. It should *not* be behaving that way, near as I can tell. I'm guessing there's some odd event happening that's unexpected. But maybe someone will have an answer after all.

Comment: I identified the closing here: https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/blob/master/aura/strike_multiSelectPicklist/strike_multiSelectPicklistController.js#L83. A workaround would be to find out if the scrollbar was clicked. Hacky! But why doesn't that fail without the modal.

Comment: can u confirm if you have lockerservice en abled?

Comment: Yes I have locker service on

Comment: @RobertSösemann that is possibly going to be the cause of it, it broke a lot of stuff. Try using standard lightning components and/or report this to appiphony so they can try to update their components to work around it

Comment: @Aequitas I opened an issue at the Strike repo but they fix veeeery slow https://github.com/appiphony/Strike-Components/issues/200. It's a very fenced and defensive open source project ;-)

Answer (score -1):

As per the screenshot, it looks like you need a picklist component. Why don't you use lightning:combobox component? There is no custom component required. You can check more about this in the link below:

> https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/aura_compref_lightning_combobox.htm

Sample code is also provided in the link below

Comment: Downvoted this as this is neighter correct (I need a customizable multi select list and not an inflexible base component with single select) and telling people to just not use something is not an answer at all. Would be good comment but not an answer.